# Какой вариант правильный?

Tags: стилистика

Здравствуйте!

Прошу дать совет! Какое вариант более правильный и почему?

1) Слушали:
Генерального директора ООО «Ромашка», который выступил с результатами хозяйственной деятельности за 2015 год и предложил...

2) Слушали:
Генерального директора ООО «Ромашка»,  который доложил итоги хозяйственной деятельности за 2015 год и предложил...

Comment: 1. Рассказал о результатах. 2. Огласил (или подвёл) итоги.

Answer (score 1):

Оба хуже. 
Но "выступил с результатами" - вообще никуда не годится, а "доложил итоги деятельности" - еще туда-сюда, хотя канцеляризм жутчайший..

Comment: ...доложил ОБ итогах...